# htaccess Rewrite with subdir subdir

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

how to i apply a subdir to the htacces containing the following.

I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/` however then I get an error, without it i am redirected to the main site.

script htaccess

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php // I tried !^/subdir/index\.php 
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

wp htaccess

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(AdsBot-Google|Android|BB10|BlackBerry\ 9350|BlackBerry\ 9360|BlackBerry\ 9370|BlackBerry\ 9380|BlackBerry\ 9780|BlackBerry\ 9790|BlackBerry\ 9800|BlackBerry\ 9810|BlackBerry\ 9850|BlackBerry\ 9860|BlackBerry\ 9900|BlackBerry\ 9930|BlackBerry9500|BlackBerry9520|BlackBerry9530|BlackBerry9550|CUPCAKE|Googlebot-Mobile|bada|dream|froyo|iPhone|iPod|incognito|s8000|webOS|webmate).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(AdsBot-Google|Android|BB10|BlackBerry\ 9350|BlackBerry\ 9360|BlackBerry\ 9370|BlackBerry\ 9380|BlackBerry\ 9780|BlackBerry\ 9790|BlackBerry\ 9800|BlackBerry\ 9810|BlackBerry\ 9850|BlackBerry\ 9860|BlackBerry\ 9900|BlackBerry\ 9930|BlackBerry9500|BlackBerry9520|BlackBerry9530|BlackBerry9550|CUPCAKE|Googlebot-Mobile|bada|dream|froyo|iPhone|iPod|incognito|s8000|webOS|webmate).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(AdsBot-Google|Android|BB10|BlackBerry\ 9350|BlackBerry\ 9360|BlackBerry\ 9370|BlackBerry\ 9380|BlackBerry\ 9780|BlackBerry\ 9790|BlackBerry\ 9800|BlackBerry\ 9810|BlackBerry\ 9850|BlackBerry\ 9860|BlackBerry\ 9900|BlackBerry\ 9930|BlackBerry9500|BlackBerry9520|BlackBerry9530|BlackBerry9550|CUPCAKE|Googlebot-Mobile|bada|dream|froyo|iPhone|iPod|incognito|s8000|webOS|webmate).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(AdsBot-Google|Android|BB10|BlackBerry\ 9350|BlackBerry\ 9360|BlackBerry\ 9370|BlackBerry\ 9380|BlackBerry\ 9780|BlackBerry\ 9790|BlackBerry\ 9800|BlackBerry\ 9810|BlackBerry\ 9850|BlackBerry\ 9860|BlackBerry\ 9900|BlackBerry\ 9930|BlackBerry9500|BlackBerry9520|BlackBerry9530|BlackBerry9550|CUPCAKE|Googlebot-Mobile|bada|dream|froyo|iPhone|iPod|incognito|s8000|webOS|webmate).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress

# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
# WPhtc: End Custom htaccess

# WPhtC: Limit upload size to 10 MB
LimitRequestBody 10485760 

# WPhtC: Protect WP-config.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# WPhtC: Protect .htaccess file
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# WPhtC: Protect comments.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*http://www.mysite.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]

# WPhtC: Disable image hotlinking
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://www.mysite.com/hotlink.png [NC,R,L]
</IfModule>

# WPhtC: Disable file hotlinking
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp3|mp4|m4a|pdf|zip|rar|doc|docx)$ http://www.mysite.com [NC,R,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using wordpress in http://www.mysite.com and than a script on http://www.mysite.com/SCRIPT/ Which holds that htaccess. trying to make that htaccess work on that subdir, when adding subdir as subscribed above, I get htaccess error

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a subdir or file for a rule, you can use [`!`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) in front of the `RewriteRule` pattern

```
RewriteRule !^subdir index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule !^subdir/index\.php$ index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: And how to include it / so rewrite applies only to subdir ? `RewriteRule (.*) ^subdir index.php??rewrite=2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Edited my question with both HTACCESS FILES, 1 from main wp site, and the other one from SCRIPT subdir, how I would I edit above files, so wp htaccess includes scripts RewriteRule